# I have 4 fields 2 fields are lookup to user, 2 fields are date/text

Tags: salesforce

I have 2 fields

1. Approveuser (lookup to user object)
2. Approveuserdate (formula field (or) text field)

when i fill the data on Approveuser, i need to diplay automaticlly on this field (Approveuserdate ) date/time.
Please help me
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear. Have you already tried something?

When user is creating / editing some record and he selects a value in 2 user lookup fields, you want to set "current date & time" in some other fields?

Try reading about workflow rules in your help & training.

I'd make a workflow similar to this:

1. Run: every time record is created or edited
2. Criteria: "User lookup field 1 - not equal to - (leave blank)"
3. Field to update: "Date/time field 1".
4. Formula to update it with: `NOW()`
5. Remember to activate the workflow.

Comment: I have 2 fields

1. Approveuser (lookup to user object)
2. Approveuserdate (formula field (or) text field) 

when i fill the data on Approveuser, i need to diplay automaticlly on this field (Approveuserdate ) date/time.

Comment: i written my scenario please help me

Comment: Yep, the workflow should work, try creating it following the steps? Just use your real field names.

Comment: Post what you have? Maybe make screenshots, upload them somewhere (you need more reputation to use the image uploader here I think) or maybe paste the workflow code into your question (edit it)?

Comment: but workflow when we click save button @ that time it will cal but i need before( when i click on lookup @ that time only)

Comment: That's very tricky to do with standard Salesforce pages. DO you need the feature so badly you're ready to use Visualforce to do it? Workflow would be the easy, supported way (configuration of SF as opposed to something custom).

Comment: Ya but my requirement like this so.

Comment: Thanks for given advise, custom controller using i written but <apex:inputtext> is working fine, but i need to use<apex:inputField>

Comment: please help me anyone

Comment: Maybe edit the question and post the code you have so far? Show what you tried...